# How to change the oData version in webide

Tags: sapui5, web-ide

I need to change my webide oData version to v1. The apps are created with v2 version automatically.I already have backend for my app according to batch operations based on v1.so I need to use that backend for my app.Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to specify the type in your manifest.json directly and can point to ODataModel v1

```json
"models": {
    "": {
        "type":"sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel",
        "dataSource":"mainService"
    }
},
```

Comment: Hi MacGregor ,I tried as you have said.this.getModel() giving me odata v1 model but when i execute   UIComponent.prototype.init.apply(this, arguments);  It is givinng me the error as  Uncaught TypeError: this.getOwnerComponent(...).getModel(...).metadataLoaded is not a function.How to solve this.By the way, im using sap-fiori masterdetail app in webide

Comment: What version of SAPUI5 are you using? I cannot see that code within the UIComponent init method. It's difficult to resolve the issue without seeing your code...I'm able to execute an application specifying sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel in my manifest.json without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you will not be able to change this with the new Freestyle Template and the manifest approach. In fact the code in the API instantiation is as follows

```js
if (!j.type) {
    switch (k.type) {
    case 'OData':
        j.type = 'sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel';
        break;
    case 'JSON':
        j.type = 'sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel';
        break;
    case 'XML':
        j.type = 'sap.ui.model.xml.XMLModel';
        break;
    default:
    }
}
```

So as per the official documentation sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel is deprecated.

However if your concern is only the batch processing, you can turn it off by this configuration in manifest file

```json
"": {
    "dataSource": "mainService",
    "settings": {
        "metadataUrlParams": {
            "sap-documentation": "heading"
        },
     "useBatch": false,     
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply..I hope that does not work for my scenario as we already implemented the backend logic based on batch opearions of v1 model.My app is totally based on batch operations.so I need batch feature.To use the new template in webide the backend has to be changed again as it is v2..If I were able to use the v1 model then no need of changing my backend logic.Iam looking solution for this.